# I am getting a Range Error when using ListView in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Error:

**RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..114: 115**

I am using `ListView` where when I am using simple `index` my code runs fine but when I put `index+1` so that I can start with 1 I get the error.

My code is something like this:

Code:

```
class Main_Index_Page extends StatelessWidget {
  Main_Index_Page({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final items = List<String>.generate(115, (i) => "index $i");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Index Example'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(items[index+1]),  <---here on this line I get the error.
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in dart start at an index of zero, so if you want to display the text based on the index and begin with one, then try the following code

```
//In array declaration

final items = new List<String>.generate(115, (i) => "index ${i+1}");

//While displaying the text just use index not index+1

Text(items[index])
```

Answer (score 1):

As Abdelkrim Bournane said in his answer arrays in dart are zero-based just use  `Text(items[index])`, but if what your are trying to do is skipping first item in the lest and use the rest of it your list will be something like this

```
ListView.separated(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: items.length -1 , // <-----
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(items[index+1]),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
      ),
```

Comment: it hasnt removed the 0 but it removed the last `listtile` when I try to do `+1` it throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use index + 1? What's your intention?
Array in dart are zero-based, so you should use the index directly without adding 1, like this:

```
title: Text(items[index])
```